# Weird result of trying run NSTimer after app comes to background

Tags: iphone, nstimer, background-process

This is my code:

```
- (void) printCount {
    NSLog(@"Current second: %i", i++);
}


- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{    
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{NSLog(@"Task expired");}];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(printCount) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (i == 10000) {
        [application endBackgroundTask:taskId];
    }
}
```

And this is log that I get:

```
....
Current second: 579
Current second: 580
Current second: 581
Current second: 582
Current second: 583
Task expired
Current second: 584
Current second: 585
Current second: 586
Current second: 587
Current second: 588
Current second: 589
Current second: 590
....
```

As I know using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` allowed only 10 minutes. I mean this `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier` has to "expired" after 10 minutes. And this is really happened ("Task expired" in log)! But why `NSTimer` continue run? o_O
Regards!

Comment: Actually that exactly what I wanted. That NSTimer will continue run even after 10 minutes. :) But why it's happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation for `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a):

> A handler to be called shortly before the application’s remaining background time reaches 0. You should use this handler to clean up and mark the end of the background task. Failure to end the task explicitly will result in the termination of the application. The handler is called synchronously on the main thread, thus blocking the application’s suspension momentarily while the application is notified.

I.e. this is just a notification that the task will expire, it is still your responsibility to close the task (and if you don't then they system will just kill it after a while).

Comment: "..kill after a while.".. Аpproximately, how much time it can take?

Comment: That is undocumented, and I expect it varies from OS release to OS release and with the amount of memory/etc currently in use on the device.